# Prevent Automapper creating object property with null values

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using Automapper with EF Core. EF entities:

```
public class Team
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid? OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}

public class Organization
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```

And corresponding DTOs:

```
public class TeamDto
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public OrganizationDto Organization { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationDto
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Type mappings:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Organization, OrganizationDto>();

cfg.CreateMap<TeamDto, Team>()
    .ForMember(teamEntity => teamEntity.Organization, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(teamEntity => teamEntity.OrganizationId, opt => opt.MapFrom(
        orgDto => orgDto == null ? null : orgDto.Id))
    .ReverseMap();
```

When I try to map from Team entity -> dto, when `Organization` is null on Team entity, TeamDto has non null `Organization` property with null values. e.g.

```
var team = new Team
{
    Name = "New Team"
};

// team.Organization is null as well as team.OrganizationId
var teamDto = s_mapper.Map<TeamDto>(team);
```

[image]

This is not desirable, as I want TeamDto's `Organization` property to be null.
I tried to configure this mapping via `ForMember` but it didn't take effect:

```
cfg.CreateMap<TeamDto, Team>()
    .ForMember(teamEntity => teamEntity.Organization, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(teamEntity => teamEntity.OrganizationId, opt => opt.MapFrom(
        orgDto => orgDto == null ? null : orgDto.Id))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(teamDto => teamDto.Organization, opt => opt.MapFrom(
        teamEntity => teamEntity.Organization == null ? null : new OrganizationDto
    {
        Id = teamEntity.Organization.Id,
        Name = teamEntity.Organization.Name
    }));
```

How can I configure this to have `Organization` property be set to null when source is also null.

One way I can achieve this is by using `AfterMap`, but I'm looking for a solution that can be applied to all such cases without specifying `AfterMap` for each case.

AutoMapper v. 9.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes `ReverseMap` just gets in the way, as it seems to be the case here. You can always avoid it and simply create the reverse map explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Null Substitution funcionallity into the ForMember..

https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Null-substitution.html

In my case, when try to load a null entity using ITyperConverter, the NullSubstitue comes in on the ForMember just like this, other wise de ReverseMap creates a instance with null values.

```
return mapping.ForMember(property, opt => { 
                opt.NullSubstitute(null);
                opt.MapFrom(mapFrom);
            });
```