# C# Automapper 10.1.1 creates instance of nested class, although all members are null

Tags: c#, automapper

So these are my classes:

```
    public class Order
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Position> positions;
    }
    public class Position
    {
        public string PositionName { get; set; }
        public Description Description { get; set; }
    }
    public class Description
    {
        public string Text1 { get; set; }
        public string Text2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class OrderDTO
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PositionDTO> positions;
    }
    public class PositionDTO
    {
        public string PositionName { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionText1 { get; set; }
        public string DescriptionText2 { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to map Order -> OrderDTO while flattening the Description class (so I use DescriptionText1 and DescriptionText2) Mappings are configured like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>().ReverseMap();
cfg.CreateMap<Position, PositionDTO>().ReverseMap();
```

If I create OrderDTO without the List property I can manage Automapper to not create a List with

```
cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
```

But when I create the OrderDTO Object like this (without the DescriptionTexts) and Map:

```
var dto = new OrderDTO() { CustomerName = "Customer1", positions = new Collection<PositionDTO>() { new PositionDTO { PositionName = "Position1" } } };
var order = ObjectMapper.Mapper.Map<Order>(dto);
```

Automapper always instantiates an object of the the Description Class, while I want it to be null.
I also tried cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues but this is true by default.

How can i configure Automapper to not create an instance of that Class if every property is null?
Edit: I cannot simply ignore the DescriptionText properties, because there are other cases, where I want to use them
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717459/prevent-automapper-creating-object-property-with-null-values/65718586#65718586

Comment: Thx Lucian Bargaoanu, I'm afraid that's the only way to solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of Lucian i managed to get it working with an explicit ReverseMap Method being configured like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>().ReverseMap();
cfg.CreateMap<Position, PositionDTO>();
cfg.CreateMap<PositionDTO, Position>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DescriptionText1 == null ? null : new Description() { Text1=src.DescriptionText1, Text2 = src.DescriptionText2}));
```

It's not nice, but it works for me